# Should i put @throws in docs?

Tags: php, documentation

Should I put `@throws` in a method docs when this exception might be thrown from inside another method that is invoked in my method?

Example

```
class ClassOne{
    /**
     * @throws MyException
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function aMethod()
    {
        if(true)
        {
            throw new MyException();
        }
    }
}

class ClassTwo{
    /**
     * @throws MyException           // should I document this line?
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function myMethod()
    {
        $classOne = new ClassOne();

        $classOne->aMethod();
    }
}
```

When generating DocBlock using PHPStorm it doesn't see the exception from ClassOne and doesn't put @throws line in the ClassTwo docs.

Comment: I think it's preference...I personally wouldn't - if I wanted to delve in deeper i'd look at `ClassOne`. Otherwise you'd end up with really bloated docs for Builders

Comment: And what about a case where method can return false or, let's say string? Should I document it as `@return bool|string` or `@return false|string` ? No `true` is being returned from method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't catch the exception you are going to use the PHP-Doc notation if you want to write clean code. The next one who uses your class get's the message insight the IDE that he has to catch the exception or passing it also through.
For running your code it doesn't matter.

Comment: And what about a case where method can return false or, let's say string? Should I document it as `@return bool|string` or `@return false|string` ? No `true` is being returned from method.

Comment: Please try to return only one kind. It's possible to mix but with higher PHP-Versions it's recommended to have a strong typing. Return a string and an empty string if it's false and then check the return value by the caller. But for the first steps it's OK to give a mixed type like you post it in your comment: @return string|bool